# Post not executed on back end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc, post

I need to make a simple upload, just to send some files to the back end from the front end. But for some odd reason I can't make a POST request.

When I make a GET request, the controller is called and the simple printing that I have in it executes.

But when I create a POST request with which I wish to send the file to the back end, all that happens is that the request is created, the java code/Spring controller is not executed, not called. But the request returns with a success, and the callback function is executed.

Here is the controller, its supper simple. Nothing serious because I can't even get it to execute.

@RequestMapping(value = "/testingPost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void postTest(final HttpServletRequest pRequest, final HttpServletResponse pResponse){

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testingPost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void postTest(final HttpServletRequest pRequest, final HttpServletResponse pResponse){

    System.out.println("TESTING....POSST.........................................................................................");
}
```

And here is the Javascript snipped from the controller.

var data = {
                    testing: 'testInfo'
                };

```
            var config = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
            };

            $http.post(urlBuilder.create("/S/S/S/" + "usglGed" + "/" + "testingPost"), angular.toJson(data), config)
                .
                then(function(response){

                    console.log("in success post");

                }, function(response){

                    console.log("in fail");
                });
```

Again nothing special. And I have no clue as to why spring controller is not executing the method. I'm not sure if there is some configuration in the project. Or I'm just not experienced enough, and I'm not seeing something.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `$http.post('/testingPost' ..` ?

Comment: I need to edit the question, I just noticed that the code part is not highlighted correctly

Comment: Umm...hmm. I can't edit my own question, I pasted in the method header an extra time, and the data part for the request is not in the snippet.